# how to distribute selenium tests on Jenkins slave nodes

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng

I have configured my test automation to run via Jenkins. On the master node I have the project and I have the selenium stand alone server. I would like to create more then one server so I can run my tests in parallel. I have created the slave machines via Java app and installed the node as a windows service. Do I need to install Firefox instance and selenium standalone servers on each machine? If yes, how can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the Selenium you're using. If you use Selenium 2.0 then you can setup a hub which you can connect additional browsers to. The hub will then farm out the tests to the browsers (or nodes) depending on what is needed

This [page](http://grid.selenium.googlecode.com/git-history/22ed3ff910401af083bf06a4d13514f4c6a623ca/src/main/webapp/how_it_works.html) is a good description

> Selenium Grid builds on the traditional Selenium setup, taking
>   advantage of the following properties:
>
> The Selenium test, the application under test, and the remote
>   control/browser pair do not have to be co-located. They communicate
>   through HTTP, so they can all live on different machines. The Selenium
>   tests and the web application under test are obviously specific to a
>   particular project. Nevertheless, neither the Selenium remote control
>   nor the browser is tied to a specific application. As a matter of
>   fact, they provide a capacity that can easily be shared by multiple
>   applications and multiple projects.